# Why should I use "git add ." again after copy files which have already "git add ." and "git commit"?

Tags: git, version-control

For network reasons, i cannot push my code to remote repository, but i wanted to work on these code in my home. so, i used "git add ." and "git commit -m " in my local repository. Then i used "git status" to make sure the work tree is clean now. After that, i copied these code to my flash, but i find there are a lot of untracked codes show in there after i used "git status". By the way, the "git log" shows the lasted log which i just committed. Why should i use "git add ." and "git commit " to track these code? And if i tracked these code again, will it affect my work tree, since i will use the code in flash to replace my local repository code. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are unsure about how Git works.  The typical use case is that the remote repository would act as the base for your code.  Every computer you use would pull from and sync with this repo.

Comment: How exactly did you "copy these codes"? If you copy the whole working directory from its root (including the .git directory) you should be able to transport it between machines on a memory stick.

Comment: Did you created a new folder on flash and git init it again then copied your content there?

Comment: @Thilo,Thanks for your answer, i copy the whole directory include .git file, and i even checked all files in .git directory. But when i use "git status", it show me all files in my project are untracted

Comment: @BittuChoudhary,thanks for your answer firstly, i just copy the root directory of my project which includes .git directory. But it show my all my files in my project are untracked when i use "git status".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks , i know i should pull my files from remote repository to sync my works, but the problems is that which i have mentioned in the post, i cannot connect to remote  repository since the bad network connection.

Comment: @oyster even if you copy the git repo from local to flash, `git status` should keep the same as the local repo. So please check if you did additional options. Or please check if you copied these files into an empty folder, and if parent/child folder on flash has other git repositories.